# Login window to create a new database connection on SQL Oracle Developer doesn't appear

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm unable to create a new database connection on SQL Oracle Developer because the login window to enter the details do not appear. Only the login windows for "Oracle NoSQL Connections" and "Database Schema Service Connections" appear.

I've tried re-installing the developer but that doesn't seem to help. I'm using a mac and have JDK 8 installed. I'm fairly new to SQL and coding in general so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Picture for Reference]

Comment: have you tried to use the `+` button ??

Comment: Yes, i've used the + button as well as right-clicking for "new connection"

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this - it will usually do the trick.

Open and bash terminal, and cd to your home directory.

Then, cd to .sqldeveloper

You should see one or more system directories, appended with the version number of SQL Developer - these directories hold the settings, connections, etc for your copy of SQLDev.

Rename that directory. Then try starting SQL Developer.

[image]

Two additional things

1. i'm assuming you have Oracle JDK and not OpenJDK - OpenJDK isn't supported
2. i'm assuming you have a recent version of SQL Developer (20.2 is latest)

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure how to rename the directory. With regards to the additional things, I have Oracle JDK and SQL Developer 20.2

Comment: you can use finder instead, but in bash just do mv system20.2* old-system20.2

Comment: I've entered the code in bash and when I opened Oracle SQL Developer, it asked if I wanted to transfer old connections or some sort. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: and did you say 'no'? Sorry, I didn't realize you had older copies of the tool on your machine. Do those versions work? Also, in the View > Log panel, do you see any error messages?

Comment: Yes I said no. I thought downloading previous versions of the developer would solve the problem but it didn't. Log panel didn't show any messages.

Comment: two more things, the welcome screen isn't showing? did you close that on your own? one last thing to try - Windows > Reset Windows to Factory Settings, then try again

Comment: I closed the welcome screen on my own. Tried to reset window factory settings but no dialog box would pop up.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have 2 monitors? Or can you try minimizing and maximizing the app? I almost wondering if the dialogs are going BEHIND the main display.

Comment: in os x, you can 3 finger swipe and see a desktop view of your windows, see if the connection dialog is there

Comment: I'm using a laptop. Minimising and maximising didn't do anything. I don't think the dialogs are going behind the display because the dialogs of the other connections pop up.

Comment: i'm out of ideas, sorry